# How to add a custom querystring to a single WordPress nav menu item?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm trying to add a querystring into a specific menu item in a WordPress menu.  I need to read a cookie, let's say sessionID, and pass that key/value pair in a query string on a single link in my nav menu. I could try this via JS/jQuery but would need to do it via PHP. I've search but found nothing int he forums that would help.

Using WordPress 3.5

Comment: Are you using Wordpress's built in menu system?

Comment: Yes I am using the built in menu system.

Comment: Boy, this sounds like it would be a lot easier in Javascript.

Comment: I've currently deployed a solution in JS but I would prefer to not rely on clientside code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function wpse_14405784( $items, $menu = 'your_menu_slug', $args ) {

    foreach( $items as $item ) {

        if ( $item->post_title == 'your_link_title'  {

            $item->url = add_query_arg( 'your_key', 'your_value', $item->url );
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items','wpse_14405784', 11, 3 );
```